# Dev Test Lab Artifact files naming convention

Tags: azure-devtest-labs, azure-lab-services

I am trying to create a new custom artefact for my dev test lab, and I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/devtest-lab-artifact-author) documentation.

What is unclear to me is the naming conventions used. If I go by the naming convention used in the example in the above link: the folder name should be "os-package" or "os-task".

But what is unclear to me (even from the example) is the naming convention for the files.There are different conventions for different files in the same folder:

- **A**rtifact**f**ile.json
- **C**hocolatey**P**ackage**I**nstaller.ps1
- **s**tart**C**hocolatey.ps1

Is there a naming convention documented somewhere that I should follow?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there have been a lot of people involved with these artifact development, and not everyone was careful with their filenames. There is not one convention used throughout, although I would suggest to use Pascal casing.

One important thing is to make sure the file `Artifactfile.json` is spelled and cased exactly so, otherwise that file may not be recognized. (`artifactfile.json` will also work)

Here is the public repo for reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-devtestlab